# How to add x-webkit-speech tag to ASP: TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to add the x-webkit-speech attribute to input boxes on my ASP.net site. How would I add the attribute x-webkit-speech to an

```
<input id="uxTextInput" value="" x-webkit-speech>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uxTextInput.Attributes.Add("x-webkit-speech", "x-webkit-speech");
```

web-kit should recognize that